# Does the kinetic energy always decrease with gain in potential energy even if the system is being provided energy externally

Tags: energy

A car accelerates uphill does its kinetic energy increase or decrease?

Comment: The kinetic energy is increasing if the velocity of the car is increasing,doesn’t matter if the car goes uphill or downhill

Answer (score 2):

Kinetic energy of the body always depends on the velocity of the body. So kinetic energy of the car can increase even if it goes up hill, as you are saying it can get that energy from other sources.

Comment: OK, That makes sense

Answer (score 0):

No it is possible to have external energy put into a system which increases its PE whilst keeping the same KE. For example, a car moving up a hill at a constant speed - the energy from the engine goes into increasing its its PE whilst the KE will remain unchanged.

It is also possible for the external energy to go into increasing both the KE and PE, for example in the situation of a car accelerating up a hill.

Comment: Ok ,now that's quite discernible